# How to serve node/express app through both http and https via Apache proxy?

Tags: apache, node.js, express

I'm creating a web app using node/express and I want to test it locally as a vhost using both http and https. currently my express app listening and works fine on both http and https through ports 3080 and 3443 (eg: `http://localhst:3080` and `https://localhost:3443`).

Then I created vhost through apache using following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName mynodedomain.com
 ServerAlias www.mynodedomain.com

 ProxyRequests off

 <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 <Location />
       ProxyPass http://localhost:3080/
       ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3080/
 </Location>
 DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/mynodedomain.com/webapp/public"
 ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/mynodedomain.com-error_log"
 CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/mynodedomain.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

it works fine and I can access express app via `http://mynodedomain.com`. what I want to do is I should be able to access the site via `https://mynodedomain.com` and it should be forward to `http://localhost:3443/`. I tried it following way

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName mynodedomain.com
 ServerAlias www.mynodedomain.com

 ProxyRequests off

 <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
 </Proxy>

 <Location />
       ProxyPass https://localhost:3443/
       ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:3443/
 </Location>
 DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/mynodedomain.com/webapp/public"
 ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/mynodedomain.com-error_log"
 CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/mynodedomain.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

but It doesn't work. can you show me a correct way to do this? thank you

Comment: are you accessing it using the correct url?I mean are you accessing it using https://mynodedomain.com and the other one using http://mynode.com.And if your configuration is in the same conf file of Apache then it should work.